# C++ ? Why the value does not change ?

Tags: c++, linked-list

I just learned how to use this operator : ->,
and I am trying to create practice programs so I can remember it and be familiar with it.
I created a program that inputs my health and then heal my (add health) using the -> operator.
But when I run program, my health stays at 50 (cause I set my current health to 50).

here is my code :

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct myhealth
{
    unsigned short my_health;
};

void addhealth(myhealth* addhealth)
{
    addhealth->my_health += 50;
};

int main()
{
    myhealth player;
    player.my_health = 50;

    cout << "My earlier health : " << player.my_health << endl;

    myhealth();

    cout << "My current health : " << player.my_health;

    cin.get()
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried stepping through the program in a debugger?

Comment: myhealth() should be addhealth(&player);

Comment: Why did you not read your main() story. Program output as per your story.

Comment: I am very ashamed right now, it is a typo. sorry

Answer (score 3):

You never call `addhealth` and so the value is never modified.

This line of code:

```
myhealth();
```

appears to have been written in error. Instead I think you meant to write:

```
addhealth(&player);
```